# Super class checking for respondsToSelector fails

Tags: ios, cocoa

I did the following code, to check, if super implement the method (using respondsToSelector)

```
- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    if ([super respondsToSelector:@selector(scrollViewWillBeginDragging:)]) {
        [super scrollViewWillBeginDragging:scrollView];
    }

    self.scrolling = YES;
}
```

but it evaluates to YES and than it breaks on unrecognized selector

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[InputFormViewController scrollViewWillBeginDragging:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x17da8670'
```

Is this the desired (faulty) behavior, or am i doing smth. wrong?

Note: super class is

```
@interface FormBaseViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
```

that doesnt implement (scrollViewWillBeginDragging:)

Comment: how is "`scrollViewWillBeginDragging:`" declared in your InputFormViewController class?

Comment: @MichaelDautermann I assume it's declared with the very same signature it's defined with. But why is that relevant?

Comment: actually its not implemented in the super class, and therefor the respondsToSelector should fail

Comment: Looks like your super class is InputFormViewController from the crash log…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[super respondsToSelector: @selector(someSelector)]` doesn't test whether the superclass implements `someSelector`. It tests whether the *current object* (i.e. `self`) responds to `someSelector`, but it does it using the superclass's implementation of `respondsToSelector:`. In other words, unless you have overridden `respondsToSelector:`, the code `[super respondsToSelector: @selector(someSelector)]` is exactly the same as `[self respondsToSelector: @selector(someSelector)]`, because you were already using the inherited version.

What you want is `[[[self class] superclass] instancesRespondToSelector: @selector(someSelector)]`.

Though I am not sure why you'd do this, since dynamic superclasses are not really supported by the language.